# Moving average ignoring NaN

Tags: matlab, nan, moving-average

I am trying to compute a moving average on multiple columns of a matrix. After reading some answers on stackoverflow, namely [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22598902/a-moving-average-with-different-functions-and-varying-time-frames) one, it seemed that the `filter` function was the way to go. However, it does not ignore `NaN` elements, and I would like to do this ignoring `NaN` elements in the spirit of the function `nanmean`. Below a sample code:

```
X = rand(100,100); %generate sample matrix
X(sort(randi([1 100],1,10)),sort(randi([1 100],1,10))) = NaN; %put some random NaNs 
windowlenght = 7;
MeanMA = filter(ones(1, windowlenght) / windowlenght, 1, X);
```

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to keep the NaNs in their respective positions and only ignore them for the purposes of each mean, not remove them completely and take the rolling average of the result?

Comment: That is correct. So if there are 7 NaNs in a row the resulting mean should be NaN. If there is a sequence [NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 5 10] the resulting mean should be 7.5.

Comment: I think you then can not use filter, and will probably need to just loop thought this. You can use filter because of the properties of FFT, but there is no mathematical formulations for NaNs

Comment: The whole goal was to avoid using an inefficient loop as I need to compute this for several large matrices. I am trying accumarray, but still haven't figure out how to do it.

Comment: The function [movmean](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/movmean.html) has a nan flag.

Answer (score 2):

Use [colfilt](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/colfilt.html) with [nanmean](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/finance/nanmean.html):

```
>> A = [1 2 3 4 5; 2 nan nan nan 6; 3 nan nan nan 7; 4 nan nan nan 8; 5 6 7 8 9]

A =

     1     2     3     4     5
     2   NaN   NaN   NaN     6
     3   NaN   NaN   NaN     7
     4   NaN   NaN   NaN     8
     5     6     7     8     9

>> colfilt(A, [3,3], 'sliding', @nanmean)                                       

ans =

    0.6250    1.1429    1.5000    2.5714    1.8750
    1.1429    2.2000    3.0000    5.0000    3.1429
    1.5000    3.0000       NaN    7.0000    3.5000
    2.5714    5.0000    7.0000    7.8000    4.5714
    1.8750    3.1429    3.5000    4.5714    3.1250
```

(if you only care about 'full' blocks, select inner rows / columns appropriately)

Alternatively, you can also use [nlfilter](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/nlfilter.html), but you then need to be explicit (via an anonymous function handle) about what you'll be doing with the block; in particular, to work with nanmean such that it will produce a scalar output from the whole block, you'll need to convert each block to a column-vector before calling nanmean in your anonymous function:

```
>> nlfilter(A, [3,3], @(x) nanmean(x(:)))

ans =

    0.6250    1.1429    1.5000    2.5714    1.8750
    1.1429    2.2000    3.0000    5.0000    3.1429
    1.5000    3.0000       NaN    7.0000    3.5000
    2.5714    5.0000    7.0000    7.8000    4.5714
    1.8750    3.1429    3.5000    4.5714    3.1250
```

However, for the record, matlab claims colfilt will generally be faster, so generally nlfilter is better reserved for situations where it doesn't make sense for your input to be converted to a column when processing each block.

Also see matlab's manual page/chapter on [sliding operations in general](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/performing-sliding-neighborhood-operations.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you have R2016a or beyond, you can use [the `movmean` function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/movmean.html) with the `'omitnan'` option.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
MeanMA = filter(ones(1, windowlenght) / windowlenght, 1, X(find(~isnan(X)));
```

This will extract the non-nan values from X.

The question is... do you still have a valid filter processing? If X is filled iteratively, one element per timestep, then the "NaN-Elimination" will produce a shorter vector which values are not aligned with the original time vector any more.

***EDIT***

To still have a valid mean calculation, the filter parameters must be updated according to the number of non-NaN values.

```
values = X(find(~isnan(X));
templength = length(values);
MeanMA = filter(ones(1, templength ) / templength , 1, values );
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I do need the resulting vector MeanMA to be aligned with the original vector X.

Comment: And what about the window length? Don't you have to set it to the length of the possibly shortened vector?

Comment: See my comment above. Let's say the window is 7 and in that window the vector is [NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 5 10], then align with the 10 I should have a mean of 7.5.

Comment: I don't think so. If your filter param are still 1/10, then the result is 1.5. You must adapt the filter Parameters according to the number of non-NaN-values..... here: 1/2

Comment: sorry... window length is 7, not 10. So the value will be approx. 2.143, not 7.5 like it should be.